# Extract Domain text from EmailAddress

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I am hoping to find a way to extract `espn` from `abcd@espn.com`

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server. Does anyone know how to write the `substring` to accomplish this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I must admit that I'm curious why this is useful?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select SUBSTRING(
  'xx.abcd@espn.com', --input string
  charindex('@', 'xx.abcd@espn.com') + 1,
  (len('xx.abcd@espn.com')-charindex('@', 'xx.abcd@espn.com'))-4
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @emailAddress TABLE (emailAddress VARCHAR(255))
INSERT  @emailAddress (emailAddress)
VALUES ('abcd@espn.com'),
       ('ab.cd@taylormade.edu'),
       ('notanemailaddress')

SELECT  IIF(emailAddress LIKE '%@%.%', -- Confirm it has valid structure
            SUBSTRING(emailAddress,
                      CHARINDEX('@',emailAddress)+1,
                      CHARINDEX('.',emailAddress,CHARINDEX('@',emailAddress))-(CHARINDEX('@',emailAddress)+1)), --Extract the domain
            NULL) -- Provide default value if not an emailAddress
        AS emailDomain
FROM    @emailAddress
```

This accounts for values that are not valid emailAddresses and returns a `NULL` (or whatever you put there) when an invalid value is encountered.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
select SUBSTRING(
        @email, --input string
        charindex('@', @email) + 1, --character just after the @
        charindex('.', @email, charindex('@', @email)) - charindex('@', @email) - 1 --distance between @ and the first . following it
        )
```

Comment: This solution will not work, if the email address has a `.` in the beginning like `firstname.lastname@example.com`

Comment: Updated to address this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for this.

```
Select substring(@email,charindex('@', @email)+1, 
charindex('.',right(@email,len(@email) - charindex('@', @email)))-1)
```

Email addresses can contain `.` multiple times before and after the `@`, this should return the first part of the domain after the `@`

Comment: This code is missing several arguments, and without commenting it's impossible to tell what you're actually trying to do.  You might test your code and add some comments.